# Libérez, Délivrez

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, conjugaison, syntaxe

In the Disney movie "Frozen" (je croix que la version francaise s'appelle "La Reine des neiges"), there is a song with a refrain of "libérée, délivrée".

I understand the translation is "liberated, delivered". However, when I first heard this song, without seeing the spelling, I heard "libérez, délivrez". The translation for this being (imperative) "liberate, deliver".

I think these are pronounced identically. Is there sound difference I'm not aware of?

If pronounced identically, is there something else which prevents the ambiguity? Would a French person immediately understand the meaning is "libéré(e)" and not "libérez"? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

The two sound exactly the same. 
Only the context can help to determine wich is wich. 
Here it is clearly "libérée" because the girl is singing how she is liberated and freed from her past, and not giving commands to liberate someone (or herself).
At least it is how I understand it :D

Comment: Perhaps my perception is influenced by the English version, which is in fact imperative ("let it go").

Comment: @BetterSense Yeah, there's no one to give orders to. If she was talking to herself she's use *tu*, not *vous*. I don't think any native French speaker would understand it as "*libérez, délivrez*" ^^

Comment: On top of that, the 2 verbs are transtitive, and it would be awkward to give an order *libérez* or *délivrez* without an object. I imagine that if someone would tell a native speaker "délivrez!", his/her reaction would be "d'accord, mais qui dois-je délivrer ?" (same with the verb *libérer*)

Comment: Nevertheless there is a case of a well-known song using the imperative: *Allumez le feu !*

Answer (score 1):

In isolation, the words are pronounced identically. However, in context, there may be a liaison after the *vous* forms. Also, while not the case here, in classical singing (and occasionally in other types too), the *e muet* may be pronounced. For example, the listener in "Vainement ma bien-aimée" knows that Mylio is referring to a female beloved, not just because that is typical of the context and because *ma* is used, but also because he hears /bjɛ̃.nɛ.me.ə/. In such a situation, it would be relatively easy to distinguish between the feminine past participle and the *vous* form.

The forms can instead be distinguished by context:

- There is no *vous* that is previously addressed.
- The next line is *Je ne mentirai plus jamais*, so it would seem that Elsa is referring to herself.

(It is entirely reasonable that one may not be able to identify a word until further context is given later. That is often how we distinguish between homophones or how we decide which of the multiple meanings of a word is applicable to a situation.)

Comment: I just realized that my example is not the best because we already have _ma_ to indicate gender, so I may replace it when I can recall a better one.